Setting up runtime environment variables in VITE React
I am using VITE React setup for my project. I am not able to change the environment variables during runtime as I understand Vite expects all environment variables during build time.
I have gone through the internet and found that we can do this by some tweaking in the code.
This is my project setup at root -

Backend(Node)

entrypoint.sh


Frontend(React-Vite)
DockerFile
package.json

Inside Dockerfile -

ARG VITE_BASE_API_URL

WORKDIR /content-hub-ui

COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./Frontend ./Frontend
COPY ./Backend ./Backend/

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-frontend
RUN npm run build-backend
RUN npm run copy-frontend-build

WORKDIR /content-hub-ui/Backend
EXPOSE 4040
CMD ["npm", "start"]

I used one entrypoint.sh which is placed inside Backend folder which is
#!/bin/sh - 1

sed -i "s#VITE_BASE_API_URL_CONTENT_HUB_VALUE#$VITE_BASE_API_URL_CONTENT_HUB#g" static/content/assets/App-*.js

exec "$@"

Now I want to edit my Dockerfile so that I can run entrypoint.sh once my build is finished. I have tried few things but they aren't working for me. Can anybody help us in changing my dockerfile so that I can run entrypoint.sh.
I have tried this -
WORKDIR /content-hub-ui

COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./Frontend ./Frontend
COPY ./Backend ./Backend/
COPY ./Backend/entrypoint.sh ./Backend/entrypoint.sh

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-frontend
RUN npm run build-backend
RUN npm run copy-frontend-build

RUN chmod +x /content-hub-ui/Backend/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/content-hub-ui/entrypoint.sh"]

WORKDIR /content-hub-ui/Backend
EXPOSE 4040
CMD ["npm", "start"]

But this isn't working for me. Anybody has any ideas what can be the solution here. Thanks in advance.
